# Conditionally Produce two different view controllers from single UITabBarItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm writing an iOS application that includes a UITabBarController, where one of the tabs is the user's profile. However, if the user is not signed in, I would like the application to display a different ViewController (Sign in/Sign up) instead.

I currently have the profile tab routing to a navigaion controller which has its RootViewController as ProfileViewController. In ProfileViewController's viewDidLoad, I have a check to see if the user is signed in. If the user is not, It performs a segue to SignInSignUpViewController which eventually loops back to ProfileViewController.

This approach is over-complicated and broken in a couple ways. For example, the navigation controller allows for the user to back into the signup/signin view controller after they've already signed in.

I feel like this is a pretty common idiom in iOS, but I can't find a good solution online. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers:animated:) method `– setViewControllers:animated:`. After you've logged in call this and pass your profile ProfileViewController. It will then be at the top of the stack, so the user won't be able to navigate back to the login view controller.